# manipulation with onmouseover, onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div tag (id=div_1), this tag has several neighbor elements, after on moseout on this tag, mouse is  over already on other elements right? I want at onmouseout on `div_1` tag, alert id element, on which is mouseover now, how make this?

```
<div id="div_1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #090"></div>
<div id="div_2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #900"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you need that specific ID? Do you mean all of the div tags or just `div_1`?

Comment: @undefined, I need id other element, on which is mouse over now, (after onmouseout `div_1` element)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

In the comments, you say

> I need id other element, on which is mouse over now

That's a different question. To do that, you'll want a combination of knowing the mouse has left the `div`, **and** knowing it's entered something else. I'd probably use a combination of `mouseleave` and `mouseover` for that, like this:

```
$("#div_1").mouseleave(function() {
    // We're leaving the div, set up to capture mouseover
    $("....selector for a container of these elements...").one("mouseover", function(e) {
        // Get the ID of the bottommost element
        console.log(e.target.id);

        // Or alternately, in case it doesn't have one
        var elementWithID = $(e.target).closest('[id]');
        if (elementWithID[0]) {
            console.log(elementWithID[0].id);
        }
    });
});
```

But I'd try really, really hard to come up with a different way to deliver the underlying requirement.

---

Original answer:

The short version:

```
$("#div_1").mouseout(function() {
    alert(this.id); // But I'd avoid alert if I were you, perhaps console.log?
});
```

But read on...

The long version:

When you set up an event handler with jQuery, when the handler is called, `this` is a reference to the DOM element you hooked the event on, and of course `id` is the reflected property for the `id` attribute.

But remember that `mouseout` *bubbles*, so you'll receive the `mouseout` event any time the mouse leaves an element that's within your `div` (any of its descendants), even if it didn't leave the `div` itself. If you just want to know when it leaves the `div` but not any of its descendant elements, use `mouseleave` instead (originally IE-only, but jQuery provides it cross-browser).

If you wanted to generalize that to, say, all divs with class `foo`:

```
$("div.foo").mouseout(function() { // Or, of course, mouseleav
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Here is that problem: `"....selector for a container of these elements..."`

is not known beforehand, what elements (and what ids) will be  as neighbors elements, for `div_1` element

Comment: @OTARIKI: You can always do `$(this).parent().one("mouseover", ...)`. That will catch the mouse entering any of `#div_1`'s **siblings** or their descendants. Or even `$(document.body).one("mouseover", ...)` since we're using `one` and the event handler will get unregistered after the first time it's called.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#container > div').mouseover( function() {
    alert ($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/CFtP5/

**EDIT**

When not using a parent element for selecting the childs. Simply use a *wildcard*, like this:

**JavaScript**

```
$("[id^=div]").mouseover (function() {
    alert ($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_1">1</div>
<div id="div_2">2</div>
<div id="div_3">3</div>
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/VPm8M/

Comment: You understood sense, but I score tell that: I need make this, without parent element

Comment: Here is that problem:
is not known beforehand, what elements (and what ids) will be  as neighbors elements, for `div_1` element

Comment: @OTARIKI Hm. Ok, than I need more of your HTML markup to find out what to do. And do you know how many elements do come before and after `div_1`?

Comment: @OTARIKI Also interesting would be, whether this should happen on all siblings of the element or just the "*real*" neighbors.

Comment: No, I dont know how many elements will be neighbors of `div_1`, may be she haves only 1 neighbor.

Comment: @OTARIKI You have to be a little more specific. Are all siblings involved with the container there the `<div>` is? Or is it only relevant for all elements that came after or before the `<div>`? Your statement is still very vague.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18414/discussion-between-otariki-and-insertusernamehere)